# Uncaught RangeError: Item index is out of range error in WebSQL Query Results

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql, outofrangeexception

I am trying to print the results to my Select statement into a list in my HTML. I am using Web SQL (This is a requirement for the project) to store my tables.

My Select Statement:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
   tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM games', [], function (tx, results) {
                  var len = results.rows.length;
                  for (i=0; i <= len; i++){
                      $('#scores ul').append('<li><span class="alley">' + results.rows.item(i).alley + '</span><br><span class="date">' + results.rows.item(i).date + '</span></li>');
                  }
                });


});
```

When I run my code, it properly displays all the records for the games table in the list, but I am getting an "Uncaught RangeError: Item index is out of range" error on this line:

```
$('#scores ul').append('<li><span class="alley">' + results.rows.item(i).alley + '</span><br><span class="date">' + results.rows.item(i).date + '</span></li>');
```

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're checking the `length` of the `rows`, not the `items`. So the count of `rows` is throwing off the loop, and it could be going over the amount of `items` in the array.

Changing

```
 var len = results.rows.length;
```

Into

```
 var len = results.rows.item.length;
```

Should do the trick

Comment: This only returned the first record of the table. I switched it back to the code I was using before and it is no longer throwing the error. I'm very confused, but as of now, no error. 

Thank you for your help